# Manipulating multiple CSV files in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to extract the data from a few different csv files and insert it into 1 CSV file, but I can't manage to create a list (records) with specific names for each field.

original files format :
[girl name, count of girl names, boy name, count of boynames]

output:
[name, count, gender]

the code i have so far is:

```
import csv

def extract_names(filename):

    inFile = open(filename, 'rU')
    csvFile = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')

    # Initialization
    records = []
    rowNum = 0

    for row in  csvFile:

        if rowNum != 0:

            # Read each row of csv file and save information  in list 'records'
            # as (name, count, gender) 
            records.append(name, count, gender)


            print('Process each row...')      

        rowNum += 1

    inFile.close()
    return(records)
```

Start main program

```
filenames = ('babyQld2010.csv', 'babyQld2011.csv', 'babyQld2012.csv', 'babyQld2012.csv', 'babyQld2014.csv')

outFile = open('babyQldAll.csv','w') 
csvFile_out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',')

for filename in filenames:
    name, ext = filename.split('.')
    year = name[-4:]     #extract year from  file names
    records = extract_names(filename)


    # Get (name, count, gender)  from  list "records", 
    # and add value of "year" and write into output file (using "for" loop )

    print("Write in csv file...")     

outFile.close()
```

Comment: Would the same name/gender combination appear in more than one file, and would you like to add the counts if that happens?

Comment: Yeah it appears in all the initial files, no need to account for duplicates (if thats what youre asking)

Comment: you seem to be skipping the first row.  Is the first row a header?  Have you tried csv.ReadDict?

Comment: the first row isn't needed as in the original files it is:
[girl name, count of girl names, boy name, count of boynames]

and when I (infuture) write to another csv i would like them to be:

[name, count, gender]

Comment: if your target is also csv, then you can append the data in the records as a row of comma-separated values of name, count and gender as records.append(name+','+count+','+gender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asuming that your first csv has column names in its first row:

```
import csv

res = []
infile = open(filename, "r")
oufile = open(oufilename, "w")
inf = csv.reader(infile)
inf.next()
ouf = csv.writer(oufile)
ouf.writerow(["name", "count", "gender"])
for row in inf:
    res.append([row[0], row[1], "F"])
    res.append([row[2], row[3], "M"])
ouf.writerows(res)
infile.close()
oufile.close()
```

Comment: Girl Name    Count of Girl names   Boy name    Count of Boy Names
Sophie     389                      Cooper  475



thats 1 row including the header which is not needed

Comment: this gives the error "list indices must be integers, not str" ??

Answer (score 0):

Use a DictReader:

```
[burhan@dev t]$ cat sample.csv
girl name, count of girl names, boy name, count of boynames
Laura,1,John,2
Sarah,3,Frank,5
[burhan@dev t]$ python
>>> import csv
>>> with open('sample.csv') as f:
...   reader = csv.DictReader(f)
...   rows = list(reader)
...
>>> rows[0]['girl name']
'Laura'
>>> rows
[{' count of girl names': '1', ' count of boynames': '2', ' boy name': 'John', 'girl name': 'Laura'}, {' count of girl names': '3', ' count of boynames': '5', ' boy name': 'Frank', 'girl name': 'Sarah'}]
```

As you say you can't use DictReader, try this version:

```
import csv

results = list()

with open('file.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   header = next(reader) # Saves the first line and skips it
   for row in reader:
      results.append(dict(zip(header,row)))

print(results)
```

Comment: EDIT##
I cant use a dict reader, what i have there is what should be used

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using "with open(..)" ??

Comment: Of course it is, but you'll have to figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This would work. You should still build a loop over all csv files, build in a safety mechanism in case you have a csv file with unequal amount of girl and boy names, and perhaps trim some whitespaces.

```
import csv
def read_gender_counts():
    sample_csv = 'GirlName, GirlCount, BoyName, BoyCount\nAnna, 4, John, 6\nMary, 5, Fred, 10'
    csvFile = csv.reader(sample_csv.split('\n'), delimiter=',')

    records = list()
    for i, row in enumerate(csvFile):
        if i > 0:
            records.append((row[0], row[1], 'F'))
            records.append((row[2], row[3], 'M'))

    print (records)
```

With output:

```
[('Anna', ' 4', 'F'), 
 (' John', ' 6', 'M'), 
 ('Mary', ' 5', 'F'), 
 (' Fred', ' 10', 'M')]
```